Google Maps - Short Url to Coordinates - Golang
I have a list of short url google map links, such as:
- https://maps.app.goo.gl/y2HccUDkhVjhWJWb8
- https://maps.app.goo.gl/6LRg48ifPQGau8bV7
- https://maps.app.goo.gl/rB4hNMWWczsQ58FP9

I need to obtain the coordinates in the server side (using Golang). How can I do that?
This is what I tried using Google's Geocoding API. I am open to other options.
    c, err := maps.NewClient(maps.WithAPIKey(myAPIKey))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("fatal error: %s", err)
    }
    r := &maps.GeocodingRequest{
        PlaceID: "y2HccUDkhVjhWJWb8",
    }
    reverseGeocodingResponse, err := c.ReverseGeocode(context.Background(), r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("fatal error: %s", err)
    }

I was expecting that the "ReverseGeocode" function returns the coordinates for the link https://maps.app.goo.gl/y2HccUDkhVjhWJWb8. Instead, I got fatal error: maps: INVALID_REQUEST - Invalid request. Invalid 'place_id' parameter.
